# jQuery or PHP code tell the visitor if Javascript is disabled

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want jQuery or PHP code tell the visitor if the Javascript is disabled.  How to do that?

Comment: How about a simple noscript element?

Comment: @Russ Cam +1, accepted comment!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To tell the visitor if javascript is disabled you can just add a message in a `<noscript>` tag: e.g.

```html
<noscript>Javascript is disabled!</noscript>
```

The message will only appear if javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative to using `<noscript>`:

```
HTML:
    <div id='no-javascript'>Hey, you don't have javascript!</div>
    ...
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     $("body").addClass("js"); 
    </script>

CSS:
#no-javascript {color:red;}
body.js #no-javascript {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 3):

No JQuery possible if javascript is disable